# Parsing a string of varying nested data structures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method that parses a string value and converts it into a selected data type, but I am having difficulty converting strings with nested data structures, eg:

```
"[1,2,3,{'hello' => 'world'}]"
```

Currently I convert using the eval method but this causes a massive security issue because the string is actually input by a user.

Is there a different way in which I can parse these types of string? I have tried JSON.parse but it doesn't like the nested hash inside of the array.

Comment: is the structure "stable"? or the syntax inserted by user will change? perhaps you could parse using regular expressions

Comment: We can assume that the structure is "stable" such that the format will always be as expected, but it doesn't 'have' to be. There is flexibility here. I thought of regular expressions too but I was imagine the regex would be quite complex?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a standard data-serialization format like JSON or YAML? That would not only solve the security issue but also make your data interoperable with pretty much every other platform.

Comment: You're right, it makes absolute sense to use a standard serialisation format. I was trying to fit a square into a circle here because I designed my system in such a way to lead me to this issue. But now I will change my design to allow me to parse using a standard format. Thanks for helping.